# Maximum limit of data that can be stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, size, limit, data-storage

We're creating an enrollment system using php for our final thesis. And it also allows attachment of documents. We are using MySQL and I was wondering  if will it store all the data in the future? How will we know the maximum limit of data that can be stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

unsigned int largest value is 4,294,967,295
unsigned bigint largest value is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: What about the overall size of all data? I mean will it depend on the size of the hard disk?

Comment: I assume it does not depend on the size of the hard disk but I can't give you a definite answer, as I am not sure.

Comment: Oh Okey. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

How big is your hard disk? That big.

It's worth noting that MySQL is not a very good document store and if you're talking about filling up a multi-TB drive with MySQL data you can be in for some serious trouble. Backing up this sort of thing becomes increasingly more expensive and onerous, you'll need specialized tools to do this reliably if your server is under load, and in cases where 99% of the data is unchanged it's very inefficient.

Often you're better off using the filesystem for storing documents and the database for any associated metadata. This keeps your working data set reasonably small and gives you a variety of storage options for your data, including network attached storage or services like Amazon S3 where you can just dump it in the cloud.

You'll also want to look at using a replicated document store like [Riak](http://basho.com/products/#riak) or [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org) if this is the primary function of your application. They offer some features that MySQL cannot easily do, especially when it comes to large binary storage.

Comment: Our system is not that big. It's only accessible within the LAN actually.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have any problems if it's not bigger than a hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store files in the database, store them in the file system and reference them from the database.  If you allow the full path to be stored, you will be able to extend the system by adding disks.